# Change specific button title in custom cell from known button tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

I have a `UITableView` with CustomCell, each Cell have a `UIButton` and than button is getting tag in **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`**

```
cell.ffButton.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.ffButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I want if the user pressed a `UIButton` it changes that button title only.

the action **changeTitle** is in my **`UITableView.m`** not in the **`CustomCell.m`** file

searched the google for something like what I need but could't find anything.

any idea ? :)

UPDATE:

My tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NotMutualCustomCell";

    notMutualCustom *cell = (notMutualCustom *) [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.ffButton.hidden = NO;
    cell.ffButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.ffButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.ffButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeTitle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specifiy different title for different states of the button:

```
   [button setTitle:@"ON" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setTitle:@"OFF" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Next, you can change state of the button in action handler for the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`event:

```
 - (void)changeTitle:(UIButton *)button
 {
   button.state = button.state == UIControlStateNormal ? UIControlStateSelected : UIControlStateNormal;
   //keep new state of the button in model 
   self.dictionary[[@(button.tag) stringValue]] = @(state);
 }
```

You must store state of the button in the model of the application. You can use dictionary for this purpose (remember to initialize values of the dictionary properly - to the correct state).

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
    //create cell 
    cell.button.state = [self.dictionary[[@(button.tag) stringValue]] integerValue];
    return cell;
 }
```

Comment: I don't want different title for different states, but i tried your code and it worked for changing the title, but the problem is that when i scroll away from the cell then scroll back to it the title changes back to the original title.

Comment: You have to keep the value of the state in you model. Every time you create new cell you have to use this value to set state of the button in cell.
I've edited my answer.

Comment: I think that current answer sove problem with inconsistent state of the button when scrolling.

Comment: i don't need the title to be changed with button state

Answer (score 0):

**custom table view cell**

```
[btnAddFriend setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnAddFriend setTitle:@"Unfollow" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**table view implementation**

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell"];
if (!cell) {
    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nibs firstObject];
    [cell.btnAddFriend addTarget:self action:@selector(followButtonTapped:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

return cell;
}

-(void)followButtonTapped:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event{

//
UIButton *followButton = (UIButton*)sender;
followButton.selected = !followButton.selected;

//
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];

// Lookup the index path of the cell whose checkbox was modified.
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];

NSLog(@"index:%@",indexPath); // you can get the index of array from here 

}
```

[Reference TableViewCell Accessory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: then how i'm going to change the button title ?

Comment: when you click the button , its state will change, as we have set up in custom cell that for select state (unfollow) and for normal its (btnAddFriend).